# Django How to know if an object exist and has a value that is equal to an object of same model

Tags: django, django-models

Here in my code, I have a models that collects data of users for a particular foreignkey object. Now I want it in a way that if an ip_address has visited a particular DetailPage, I create an instance. But now, if an IP address has already visited this particular detail page, I don't want it to create an instance anymore, instead it should update the instance. But now this is where the problem lies; if an IP address has visited a particular IP address (my first DetailPage) and now tries to visit my second DetailPage object, it does not create an instance because the IP address already exists. I want it to create an instance because the logistic foreignkey is a different foreignkey (my Second Detail Page) and not the first because this IP address was in the first. Here's my code below:

```
models.py
class UserVisitOfLogisticDetailPage(models.Model):
    logistic = models.ForeignKey(Logistic, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    user_ip_address = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    user_latitude = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    user_longitude = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    user_city_location = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    user_country_location = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    user_device_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    user_browser_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    user_browser_version = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    user_os_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    user_os_version = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_ip_address
```

```
views.py
def logistic_detail_view(request, slug):
    logistic = get_object_or_404(Logistic, slug=slug)
    website_url = "www.google.com"

    if request.method == 'GET':
        user_ip_address = get_ip_address(request)
        user_latitude = get_user_latitude(request)
        user_longitude = get_user_longitude(request)
        user_city_location =  get_user_city_location(request)
        user_country_location = get_user_country_location(request)
        user_device_type = get_user_device_type(request)
        user_browser_type = get_user_browser_type(request)
        user_browser_version = get_user_browser_version(request)
        user_os_type = get_user_os_type(request)
        user_os_version = get_user_os_version(request)

        if UserVisitOfLogisticDetailPage.objects.filter(user_ip_address=user_ip_address).exists():
            pass
        else:
        
        # OrderItem.objects.create
            UserVisitOfLogisticDetailPage.objects.create(
                logistic = logistic,
                user_ip_address = user_ip_address,
                user_latitude = user_latitude,
                user_longitude = user_longitude,
                user_city_location = user_city_location,
                user_country_location = user_country_location,
                user_device_type = user_device_type,
                user_browser_type = user_browser_type,
                user_browser_version = user_browser_version,
                user_os_type = user_os_type,
                user_os_version = user_os_version,
            )


    context = {
        "object": logistic,
        "website_url": website_url
    }
    return render(request, 'logistic/logistic-detail.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1):

> (...) if an IP address has already visited this particular detail page, I don't want it to create an instance anymore, instead it should update the instance...

Use get_or_create() and then update your object.

> (...) I want it to create an instance because the logistic foreignkey is a different foreignkey...

I think you should simply add logistic to your filter.

As a whole this should look like:

```
detail_page = UserVisitOfLogisticDetailPage.objects.get_or_create(
    user_ip_address=user_ip_address,
    logistic = logistic
)
detail_page.update(
    user_latitude = user_latitude,
    user_longitude = user_longitude,
    ... {rest of your values} ...
    )
```

Comment: I have the update code working successfully. Now I am unable to create a new instance for when a user have not visited a second logistic detail page simply because the IP_address is in the list of created instance and is restricting me to create a new instance for a second logistic detail page.

Comment: Did you add `logistic = logistic` parameter to get_or_create?

Comment: Yes, I did, but it's not working

Comment: Voila, it's working, much respect :) all thanks to you.